# BTC Node for Dummies

Tags: nodes

Just downloaded, and I am now running a BTC pruned node.  Is there a good primer or beginner's guide to running it?  I have more questions than I think I can ask in one post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope admins is not angry that I will share the link to another forum. On the bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5208641.0 you can find big discussion about pruned node - full node. There you will find a lot of useful information